# Decipher this expression

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Let $a, b, c, d$ be digits from $0$ to $9$.  We are given that: $ab + cab + dcab = dabb$. Each number figuring in the expression cannot begin with $0$. Thus $a \ne 0, c\ne 0, d \ne 0$. Let S be the sum of all the possible values of  $dabb$. Find $S/10$. (This problem is taken from a math competition: each answer is a number from $0000$ to $9999$; if your result is not an integer, give its integer part; if it's greater than $9999$, give the last four digits; if it's negative or there's no solution, give $0000$).

What I tried: We have $b+b+b \equiv b \pmod{10}$, from which it follows that $b = 5$ or $b = 0$. If $b = 0$ we have: $a+a+a \equiv b \equiv 0\pmod{10}$; thus $a = 0$, contrary to the initial conditions. If $b = 5$, we may rewrite:$$a5 + ca5+dca5 = da55 $$Hence $3a+1\equiv5 \pmod{10}$, or $a\equiv8 \pmod{10}$, so $a = 8$. Similarly: $2c+2 \equiv 8 \pmod{10}$, or $c \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$. It follows that $c=3$ or $c=8$. It's easy to see that $c=8$ is impossible. So:$$85+385+d385 = d855$$. This is true for all valid $d$. Finally: $S = 1855+2855+...+9855 = 52695$, so $S/10 = 5269,5$, and the answer is $5269$. However the correct solution is $3413$. What's wrong with mine?

Comment: Are a,b,c, and d different, or can they be the same? Because if they have to be different, then you should exclude 8855 and 5855 and 3855

Comment: It is often a condition of such problems that different letters must represent different digits.  That does not seem to be clearly prescribed in your wording of the problem, but it would limit the choices for $d$ by a third, approximately the discrepancy in the two answers.

Comment: Also 3855...what a f***....I spent 1 hour to check why I was doing wrong

Comment: Now it gets 3413...thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the digits have to be different, you have to exclude 8855, 5855, and 3855. So that leaves 34125, so S = 3413